# Send server side Google Analytics data without sending server location

Tags: javascript, node.js, google-analytics, server-side, measurement-protocol

I am using Google Analytics client side.

Server-side I send e-commerce data and events to Google Analytics. However it's also sending the location of the server. Add the realtime overview I can see a lot of visitors in the same location where the server is located. My guess is that Google Analytics figures from the server-side events the user's location.

How can I prevent this?

```
var ua = require('universal-analytics');

function sendTransaction(analyticsProperty, {clientId, transactionId, profit}) {

    const totalProfit = +profit.toFixed(2);

    const visitor = ua(analyticsProperty, {
        cid: clientId,
        aip: 1 
    });
    visitor.transaction(transactionId, totalProfit).send();

    visitor.event('Transaction', 'Complete', '', totalProfit).send();
}

export function transactionCallback(transaction) {

    sendTransaction('UA-XXXXXX-1', transaction);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have the users ip you can use the [user ip override](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/protocol/v1/parameters#uip), location should then be determined from the ip (which is anonymized the same way the aip parameter does).

Specifically build for the purpose is the [geographical override](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/protocol/v1/parameters#geoid). More difficult to implement, since you need to determine the [geo id](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/protocol/v1/geoid) yourself and pass it in via your request.

Answer (score 0):

I would move it to client-side javascript.

Lets say you are making an Ajax Request for purchase processing, if it returns success - trigger the measurement protocol event.